# Determine the resultant using triangle method - Analytical Method - Vector Quantity - Physics

Tags: physics

I'm having some problems finding the resultant in my physics subject.

So heres the given problem:

A = 10 meters
B = 20 meters 30°

The graph looks like this:

A is in between Q1 and Q4 in x axis
the B is in Q2...

I need to find:
a. A + B
b. B - A
c. -A - R

Can you guys give me explanation of how did you find the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As B is in the 2Q, assumed that B makes an angle of 30 degrees with the negative x axis while A should be on the positive axis.  Let i and j be the unit vector along the positive x and y axes respectively.  Then we have

$$A = 10i$$

$$B = - 20cos30 i + 20sin30 j = -17.32i + 10j$$

Therefore

$$A + B = -7.32i + 10j$$
$$magnitude = 12.39$$

$$B - A = -27.32i + 10j$$
$$magnitude = 29.09$$

$$-A - B = 7.32i - 10j$$
$$magnitude = 12.39$$